# build website 'online help' with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

Starting with a website build with AngularJS as frontend and a ReST API set as backend. I would like to append an online help content.
Does exist a project or a framework to do that quickly (using angularjs powerfull) ?

I have no special mandatory requirements. I think that two concept could be important:

- help section representation as a tree,
- quick link between webapplication and online help.

Answer (score 0):

[JHipser](https://jhipster.github.io/) may be the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to build it without additional framework:

- a flat json file that describe the structure and contents of my online help,
- a controller with `$http.get(...)` embedded to get back the content
- a dedicated help page : I re-use the [bootstrap help](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) menu and I use the `ng-repeat` directive to show the active content.

(Anyway Thanks @Shaojiang Cai for your suggest).